# How to use python subprocess.check_output with root / sudo

Tags: python, subprocess, sudo

I'm writing a Python script that will run on a Raspberry that will read the temperature from a sensor and log to Thingspeak. I have this working with a bash script but wan't to do it with Python since it will be easier to manipulate and check the read values. The sensor reading is done with a library called loldht. I was trying to do it like this:

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_output
output = check_output("/home/pi/bin/lol_dht22/loldht", timeout=10)
```

The problem is that I have to run the library with sudo to be able to access the pins. I will run the script as a cron. Is it possible to run this with sudo?

Or could I create a bash script that executes 'sudo loldht' and then run the bash script from python?

Comment: It seems I can also do this from subprocess import STDOUT, check_output
check_output(["sudo", "/home/pi/bin/lol_dht22/loldht", "7"], timeout=10)

Comment: Problem with that is you will need the user that invokes the python script to be in the sudo list (otherwise that user can't call sudo), so you're back at my answer: putting the command into a privileged user, in which case you won't need to sudo in the subprocess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I will run the script as a cron. Is it possible to run this with sudo?

You can put `python script.py` in the cron of a user with sufficient privileges (e.g. root or a user with permissions to files and devices in question)

I don't know which OS you're using, but if Raspbian is close to Debian, there is no need for sudo or root, just use a user with sufficient permissions.

> It seems I can also do this `check_output check_output(["sudo", "/home/pi/bin/lol_dht22/loldht", "7"], timeout=10)`

Sure but the unix user that's going to invoke that Python script will need the sudo privilege (Otherwise can't call the `sudo` from `subprocess`). In which case you might as well do as above, run the cron from a user with the required permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can run sudo commands with cron. Just use sudo crontab -e to set the cron and it should work fine.

Comment: I'm doing something similar, using passwordless access for this script under another account and the commmand `sudo -u acctname scriptname.sh` but it won't run from cron although the same command runs from the prompt. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should very careful with running things as `root`. Since `root` has access to everything, a simple error can potentially render the system unusable.

The proper way to have access to the hardware as a normal user is to change the permissions on the required device files.

It seems that the utility you mention uses the [WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) library. Some digging in the [source code](https://git.drogon.net/?p=wiringPi;a=blob;f=wiringPi/wiringPi.c;h=503151f61014418b9c42f4476a6086f75cd4e64b;hb=HEAD) indicates that it uses the `/dev/gpiomem` (or `/dev/mem`) devices.

On raspbian, device permissions are set with `udev`. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147494/how-can-i-set-device-rw-permissions-permanently-on-raspbian) and also [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=238003).

You could give every user access to `/dev/gpiomem` and other gpio devices by creating a file e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/local.rules` and putting the following text in it:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="gpio*", MODE="0666"
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="i2c-[0-9]*", MODE="0666"
```

The first line makes the gpio devices available, the second one I2C devices.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have yet to try it and haven't decided yet if I should put the job in the cron of a user with enough permissions or make the gpio available for everyone.